# Datatables jQuery $(document).ready not working and being replaced by numbers

Tags: jquery, html, perl, datatables, cgi

I'm trying to initiate a DataTables instance with the following code...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

But when I access the HTML via web the browser shows an **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number"** error and this is how the source looks from the browser...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
0 11 4 3 2 1 0document).ready(function() {
    0 11 4 3 2 1 0'#example').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

As you can see some instructions have been replaced by the numbers "0 11 4 3 2 1" and I don't know what is causing it.

jQuery is src from Google and the DataTables javascript from their CDN.

I'm creating the HTML from a Perl script using CGI, printing the Content-type:text/html header and used different !DOCTYPEs... but still nothing. Editing the code shows no hidden chars.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Best,
e.

EDIT: This is the Perl code creating the HTML...

```
use Switch;
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser';

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";

print qq{<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
} );
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>};
```

Comment: What does the class init do?

Comment: Please show the Perl code that generates your HTML.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal not sure, is one of all the tries but is on one of the original DataTables example file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `qq` interpolates variables and your HTML string contains the special variable `$(`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
```

According to `perldoc perlvar`:

> **$(**
>
> The real gid of this process.  If you are on a machine that supports membership in multiple groups simultaneously, gives a space separated list of
>                  groups you are in.  The first number is the one returned by `getgid()`, and the subsequent ones by `getgroups()`, one of which may be the same as the first
>                  number.

Each occurrence of `$(` in your string is replaced with the list of GIDs that your webserver user belongs to.

You can see this on the command line:

```
perl -wE 'say qq{$(document).ready(function()}'
```

outputs

```
3000 3000document).ready(function()
```

on my system.

Use `q` instead of `qq` to avoid interpolating things as Perl variables.

Comment: alternatively, if you do actually want to interpolate some variables, escape every `$` that doesn't start a variable (e.g. `\$(document).ready`)

Comment: One more alternative I have used, change your jQuery onReady, you probably should anyway, to something like `jQuery(function(jQ) { …`. Then just use `jQ` everywhere you would have used `$`.

Comment: @Ashley When you start bastardizing your JavaScript code like that, you should probably look at putting it in separate, static files or using a templating system like [Template Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/).

Comment: Thank you for noticing my qq's typo @ThisSuitIsBlackNot!

Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Bastardizing? That’s a well known jQuery idiom used sometimes just for dealing JS conflicts. It’s also the recommended way over the `ready` stuff. I use TT2. I have a plugin on the CPAN for it. I also use Alloy, Xslate, and others; I also do inline stuff and one-offs.